# Can a jQuery selector find elements based on their data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an application with a considerable amount of checkboxes. Each of them has a jQuery data parameter indicating which group they belong to, e.g. `<input type="checkbox" class="show" data-group="zones" />`

In some cases I would like to select a subset of these checkboxes based on the data they contain. Can a jQuery selector pull this of? If not, are there any other ways of doing this short of manually filtering?

Comment: +1, Lets see if we get more answers on this

Comment: Can you show a sample what your proposed selector should look like?

Comment: I was thinking something like `$("input:data('group'='zones')");`, or perhaps even `$("input").dataEquals('group', 'zones');`

Comment: Thats almost indentical to the solution in my answer.

Comment: Except for the **very** important difference I've specified. There's a huge difference (or at least there could be) between the attribute of a HTML element and the jQuery data associated with that HTML element

Comment: Not that I know of, jQuery, integrates itself to the data attribute, making it easier to read and manipulate.

Comment: From what I understand jQuery assigns the HTML `data-*` attributes to it's data object when a jQuery wrapper is "initialized". Any changes made to the data object would not reflect in the HTML, thus not reflect in selectors that filter by HTML attributes. I could be wrong of course... It would be nice to get a confirmation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, one way is simply

```
$("input[data-group='zones']");
```

**Update:**

Changing the value of the data can also be done like this

```
$("input[data-group='zones']").each(function() {
   $(this).data('group', 'newzone');
});
```

Comment: True, I thought of that, but that filters by the data-* attribute of the HTML element, not the actual data of the element in Javascript. For instance, if I were to set some data on an element through Javascript and try this method it would fail. @AllanKimmerJensen I have read the documentation :-)

Comment: @Codemonkey, IT should not fail, if you want to change the datas too. Wait for my update

Comment: Okay, clearly I'm being misunderstood :P My concern is that **if** I were to set some data on an element through Javascript then the jQuery selector (`$("input[data-group='zones']");`) would fail. This is because `data-group=abc` is a HTML element attribute, not the actual data itself. The data is derived from the HTML attribute, not the other way around. I want to select elements based on the data they contain, **not** their HTML5 `data-*` attributes.

Comment: @Codemonkey, Of course, since it selects multiple elements you should use `.each()` to set the value. IF you are sure the element is going to be only one, then `$("input[data-group='zone']")[0].data("group", "abc");`

Comment: Again, my question has nothing to do with setting data. Setting data is easy, I can do that. I'm wondering if jQuery supports a selector that finds elements based on their **actual data**, not their HTML5 `data-*` attribute

Answer (score 0):

After researching a bit, There is also another way, using filter()

```
var inputs = $('input').filter(function() { 
  return $(this).data("groups") == true 
});
```

Next manipulate as a whole

```
inputs.each(function() {
    $(this).data('groups', 'new zone');
});
```

Or you modify the single element

```
inputs[0].data('groups', 'new zone');
```

Comment: This is what I meant by "manually filtering" :-) I was hoping jQuery could do this using a selector. But thanks

Comment: @Codemonkey, Extend the default function then, make your own feature.